# How to create Servlet and/or JSP project on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I've installed tomcat 7, javaservlet 3.0 and openjdk 7. I have examples installed but I can't find them on disk only from the browser. Tomcat docs say that I need my app in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/` subdirectory but I don't have such varaible.

I've created a directory `myapp` in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT` with `myapp/WEB-INF/classes/Servlet.java` (I've compile the file) and `myapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">
    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class> 
        <description>This is a simple Hello World servlet</description> 
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

But when I go to localhost:8080/myapp/test I have error 404. this is my servlet:

**UPDATE** I change my root directory to webapps/myapp the index.html file is loading (using `localhost/myapp/index.html`) but my servlet keep getting 404. The error is different then normal error because I don't have a message (with URI) like with wrong urls like `/foo/bar`.
Here is the code for my serlvet (hello world example):

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your folder shouldn't be under `/webapps/ROOT`.  It should just be right under `/webapps/`

Comment: @IanMcLaird thanks, I changed it, but still got error 404. But now `myapp/index.html` is loading.

Comment: You say that the messages are different for (known) bad URLs than they are for the servlet.  How are the messages different?  Does anything show up in the tomcat logs?

Comment: @IanMcLaird I don't have message at all for the `/myapp/test` but for `/foo/bar` I have URI as message. I got error `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstance
Manager can not access a member of class Servlet with modifiers ""`

Comment: @IanMcLaird I found the issue there is no constructor.

Comment: You shouldn't need to write a constructor for a servlet, but now that you say that...Your `TestServlet` class should be `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work when I added empty constructor to my class.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Eclipse EE to generate and maintain dynamic web projects? It is much easier to let the IDE handle the project structure. Plus you can find many guides on how to use Eclipse for generating dynamic web projects.

Greetings

Comment: I've try but not success. Besides I don't want to rely on magic, I want to know how it work.

Comment: Ok, did you put your "myApp" folder into /webapps/ or into /webapps/ROOT/? Because when you try to call localhost:8080/myapp/Servlet the structure should be /webapps/myapp/

Comment: I've change the path but still get the 404 error, but it's different then when I type some different url (when url is not found I got message the URI but when I type `/myapp/Servlet` I don't have message).

Comment: But when I type `localhost:8080/myapp` I got index.html file.

Comment: If your servlet doesn't yet produce any output, you would get nothing when you go to `/myapp/Servlet`  Going to `localhost:8080/myapp` would launch the `welcome-file`, which may be index.html.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I have hello world servlet.